# Easiest and free way to transform bitmap image into geographical map

Tags: graphics, vector-graphics, kartograph

I have image that is the map of a country with districts. For example this image http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/POLSKA_mapa_powiaty2.png. I want to trace/convert it to svg format to have each district as separate shape (polygon) - and later I want to use it in `http://kartograph.org/`. What program I have to use? And how?

I tried so far inkscape/photoshp but those didnt work.
Is there maybe some special tool/program to trace/convert bitmap to vectors?

Comment: You would probably be better off starting with lat/long data from a site like http://www.gadm.org/ and transform it directly into SVG mark up (That's what I'm doing to learn SVG/Canvas).

Comment: The information is very hi-res, so you will probably need to downgrade the number of points in your SVG to a manageable level.  I'm in the process of figuring out how to do this so that the hi-res data is only downloaded to a users browser when they have their canvas at a particular zoom level... at the moment the UK map is 14MB of HTML...  rather too much information...

Comment: Quick tip to get a head-start. The .KMZ format is .KML zip compressed - if you rename the file as .zip you can extract the contents into "normal" text - which you will quickly realise is XML (and fairly easy to understand).

Comment: dav: I download data in *.shp format and then I use kartograph.py with `simplify` option which reduces number of points in each path. So you get less details & less data to download. But I have no idea how to adjust this dynamicly. Maybe make two maps - one simplified and one in details and show the first one and download second one in background?

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  I'm going to be loading the points into SQL and then selecting the points appropriate to a zoom level - or that's my plan at the moment.